# How can I delete multiple rows in a database table where specific conditions are not met?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to delete specific rows in a database table where specific conditions are not met.
This is the SQL command:

`DELETE FROM table WHERE URL NOT LIKE "%/meldung/%" or NOT LIKE "%/artikel/%"`

I want to delete every row in the URL column which does not contain /meldung/ or /artikel/, but this command just keeps the rows which contain /artikel/ AND /meldung/ in the URL.

Somebody can help?

Comment: You need to use `AND` instead of `OR` here.  You want matching rows where it's NOT `meldung` AND it's NOT `artikel` (i.e. it IS everything else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use either

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE not(URL LIKE "%/meldung/%" or URL LIKE "%/artikel/%")
```

or

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE (URL not LIKE "%/meldung/%" and URL not LIKE "%/artikel/%")
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below you missed column name after or

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE URL NOT LIKE "%/meldung/%" and 
URL NOT LIKE "%/artikel/%"
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but this deleted everything from my table.

Comment: @gython could you please share sample data and expected delted rows?

Comment: Hi @Zaynul unfortunately I am not allowed to do this, but I just used AND instead of OR and it worked.

Comment: @gython ok then edited im according to your working version but due to lack of explanation in question it tough to understand